# Data on demographics at the neighborhood level in Oakland

Tags: city

I am trying to find recent information on the racial, socioeconomic (income, education, etc), age, etc composition of neighborhoods (zip code is too general for my purposes) in Oakland.

If anyone knows of a good source, that would be awesome!

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oakland has an open data portal. This dataset contains the outlines (Shapefile or KML) for the neighborhoods.

https://data.oaklandnet.com/Property/Oakland-Neighborhoods/7zky-kcq9

Unfortunately it has very little data related to what you are looking for. Where it does, the datasets lack Lat/Lon coordinates. One would need to bulk geocode the datasets and check which neighborhood (e.g., KML polygons) the location fits into.

You can get the KML files for Census Tracts and Block Groups from the US Census at this link:

https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/tiger-kml.html

Combining the two you should be able to map any demographic resource based on Census Tracts/Blocks to the Oakland neighborhoods. If you do go through this effort, I would suggest making the mapping of the census tract/blocks mapping to neighborhoods publicly available in Github.

Comment: Saweet!  Thanks for the links.  Yeah, once I mash them up, I'll definitely post the data online.  I would upvote your comment but I don't have the rep to do it.